# How to define a private color in a (possibly LaTeX3) package?

Tags: color, latex3, privacy

Suppose I'd like to define, in a personal package `mypackage`, a private (`xcolor`'s) color:

```
\definecolor{my_so_beautiful_red}{rgb}{1,0,0}
```

the name of which I'd like to not be accidentally used by authors or in another package/class. What would be the best way for this aim, especially if this package is allowed to make use of LaTeX3 features?

Comment: As soon as one has access to the code, the secret will be revealed.

Comment: Indeed, but this will then be intentional. My aim is to provide a color which could not (would have very low probability to) be accidentally used elsewhere, either in another package/class or by authors (I'll edit my question to precise the point on authors), in the spirit of private macros.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé: The only option then is to give it a weird name that no-one would accidentally use. When in doubt, throw in some `@` signs as well...

Comment: Unfortunately `@` is not forbidden in color names defined by authors (by contrast to macro names).

Comment: @egreg `egreg`'s method is not so safe if it is adopted not only by you but also by other class or package authors. Why don't you just use some name like `\definecolor{Denis_Bitouze_red_20140918-22h18mn}{rgb}{1,0,0}` ?

Comment: @jfbu Sure, but hitting the same name without peeking at the code is not likely, if combined with your suggestion of a long and not easily predictable name.

Comment: I'm confused as to why you would want this, though…

Comment: In order to decrease probability the end user have to face error or an unexpected result in case he, or a package he's using, defines a color already defined by my package. That's not that crucial but, in fact, it's more a general question on how define private constants (here color constants) in the spirit of private macros that cannot be redefined by the end user (with names containing an `@`). If I understand well, LaTeX3 aims to go further for macros by lowering the probability for a private one of a module (a package) to be defined by another module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the short answer that we don't yet have a "LaTeX3" way for this as there isn't yet a full l3 color model implemented, i.e., we don't have expl3 code manipulating color

But as a general approach, the only really safe way that I can see is to have the ability to define constants representing color. In that case a "name" would gain a fixed meaning any any additional approach to redefine it would generate a warning or error.

The attempt to use a "private" name by choosing an uncommon name is only making it less likely to get the color overwritten. But as long as we don't have the ability to define constants and you have to rely on the color package interface that 2e provides that is probably the best you can do as explained by egreg.

Answer (score 9):

When a color is specified by name, the `\csname...\endcsname` feature is used, and characters inside it are used independently of their category code, provided this code is not 0 (escape), 9 (ignored), 13 (active), 14 (comment) or 15 (invalid). The usual reading rules apply, though, so you might use the fact that byte 0 is normally of category code 9:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}

\catcode`\^^@=12
\definecolor{my^^@private^^@color}{rgb}{0.5,0.4,0.9}
\newcommand{\myHello}{\textcolor{my^^@private^^@color}{Hello}}
\catcode`\^^@=9

\begin{document}

\myHello

\textcolor{my^^@private^^@color}{Hello}

\end{document}
```

This document will raise the error

```
! LaTeX Error: Undefined color `myprivatecolor'.
```

and print

[image]

The trick is to revert to the normal setting once the macros using the private color have all been defined.

Of course everybody will be able to spot the definition of your color by activating `\tracingmacros` in their document or, more simply, with a color analyzer.

Comment: Very clever! Is there a "LaTeX3 way"?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé The same: `\char_set_catcode_other:N \^^@` and then `\char_set_catcode_ignore:N \^^@` for reverting.